# Hosting a server on a private IP address

Tags: java, sockets, networking, ip-address, router

A server application, written in Java, will be hosted on an IP address provided by the router. How can a client connect **from anywhere** to the server even though the server doesn't have a public IP, just an IP address provided by the router using NAT translation?

Comment: If your router is providing you with an `IP` but `NAT` is enabled it is perfectly routable to. You might need to change some settings to let it through at certain ports and stuff though.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to configure a Port Forwarding on your router.

1. The clients from "anywhere" will connect to the router by its public IP address and the port used for your application (or a different port, but a port you need to define).
2. The router will use its port forwarding configuration to find the IP address and the port an incoming connection on a certain port shall be forwarded to.
3. Your router then establishes the connection to your server.

A disadvantage of having your server behind a router using NAT is it gets complicated if you want to have https connections.

Comment: I don't get it how come softwares such as u torrent can implement P2P communication without Configuring port-forwarding manually ?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong **Purpose of Torrent like software is** that to reduce massive computing and Save bandwidth while distributing the load so that every one is seeding the data instead of One server and also if it implements the design where all data goes through the main server then what's the point of that P2P communication ? **My Point** When someone is seeding some data they are acting as a Mini Server on a IP which is assigned to them by a router.

Comment: P2P Software cannnot pass a NAT router without help. This help may either be a port forwarding or a router allowing UPNP configuration, relaying over a central server or other peers or inverting the connection.

Comment: I found **Cling - Java/Android UPnP library and tools** Does that mean this problem can be solved automatically by coding or manually is the only way to go, any Idea ?

Comment: You can *solve* the problem for some users. And it works quite well, as most of the routers support UPnP, but it is nothing that always works because users with more technological knowhow often deactivate UPnP because they do not want any Software to be able to change their forwardings.